# Why "decimal.Decimal('0') < 1.0" yields False in Python 2.6.5

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

In Python 2.6.5 the following expression yields False:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('0') < 1.0
False
```

Is there a rationale explaining why comparison of Decimal against float should behave like this?

Comment: No repro on Python 2.7 or 3.1 - don't have 2.6.5 installed here so I can't check that.

Comment: Confirmation for 2.6.6 - the problem may have something to do with: `decimal.Decimal('0') + 1.0` raising `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'float'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [python decimal comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062008/python-decimal-comparison)

Comment: Yes repro on Python 2.4.4 and 2.5.2

Answer (score 13):

From the [documentation of the decimal module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html):

> Changed in version 2.7: A comparison
>   between a float instance x and a
>   Decimal instance y now returns a
>   result based on the values of x and y.
>   In earlier versions x < y returned the
>   same (arbitrary) result for any
>   Decimal instance x and any float
>   instance y.

So it looks like that was a bug/missing feature and all you need to do is upgrade.