# What is the logic behind order comparison on non-numeric Python objects

Tags: python, implementation

Why does `123 < list` evaluate to `True`? Or `list < 123` to `False`? Or `list < dict` to `True`?

More generally why do `<` or `>` not raise errors when a number is compared to a function, a list or such things? What's the logic behind this design choice?

(note that this is in Python 2.7, it might not be true in Python 3 I didn't try it yet)

Comment: These throw errors like you'd expect in python 3.

Comment: You will find answer to this question more informative than the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062008/python-decimal-comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python2, the [docs say](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except
>   numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types
>   that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

In Python3, [this wart is fixed](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> The ordering comparison operators (<, <=, >=, >) raise a TypeError
>   exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering.
>   Thus, expressions like 1 < '', 0 > None or len <= len are no longer
>   valid, and e.g. None < None raises TypeError instead of returning
>   False. A corollary is that sorting a heterogeneous list no longer
>   makes sense – all the elements must be comparable to each other. Note
>   that this does not apply to the == and != operators: objects of
>   different incomparable types always compare unequal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison in such cases is done on the bases of `type()` of the objects:

for example : `type(123)` is `'int'` and `type(list)` is `'list'`, so the string comparison of `'int'<'list'` returns to be `True`

```
>>> 123<list
True
>>> type(123)<type(list)
True
```