# String conversion to Decimal explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

I dont understand the results:

```
a1 = Decimal(9999.99)
a2 = Decimal('9999.99')
b = float(9999.99)
a1 > b  # false
a2 > b  # true <-- ???
a2 > a1  # true <-- ???
```

In a web app, I wrote `max_value=9999.99` and the field where the user could type a value was a char field hence the conversion from a string like the `a2` variable and the comparison gave this unexpected comparison. Could you explain it?

Comment: What's the precision of `float` and `decimal`? What happens if you print each value? I suspect the. number is unrepresentable as a floating point, resulting in a trail of 9s up to the 10th or 15th digit, followed by extra digits

Comment: Basically, if you have a float *literal* (unquoted `9999.99`) anywhere in your code, say goodbye to any specific *expectations* you have have about that value.

Comment: be careful compare/converting floating point.  Most computers can't store exact values.

Comment: `a1` prints `Decimal('9999.989999999999781721271574497222900390625')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062008/python-decimal-comparison#1062030 Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

The float value `9999.99` is not exactly equal to 9999.99 because it's stored in binary, not in decimal. The decimal value `Decimal('9999.99')` is *exactly* equal to 9999.99 because it was created from a decimal expression. The decimal value `Decimal(9999.99)` is not exactly equal to 9999.99 because it was created from a float value; and it is not exactly equal to the float value `9999.99` because it has been converted to decimal.

Comment: it's basically shown in [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial) - and I think the point here is that `Decimal` is different from the "normal" built-in `float`

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of thre `decimal` class is, to preserve precision during subsequent computations.

In your example

```
 decimal(9999.99)
```

you are effectively failing right from the start, since you feed in an inexact float value.
All subsequent unexpected results are implied by having this one comparison operand not well-defined.